# Can weighted data be used with the CrossTable function in R?

Tags: r, survey

I have attached sample weights to my data using the code below;

```
s_w <- couple_dta$h_sw /1000000
design <-svydesign(ids =~s_unit + hh, strata =~res , weights = s_w ,data =c_dta)
```

I had earlier created crosstables with unweighted data using the code;

```
CrossTable(c_dta$varA, c_dta$varB, prop.c = FALSE ,prop.r = FALSE , prop.chisq = FALSE , format = "SPSS")
```

The result of CrossTable with unweighted data is something below.

```
                              Variable B 

Variable A           |     f     |  mf       |  m        | Row Total | 
---------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
             m       |      n1   |      n2   |      n3   |n1 +n2+n3  | 
                     |n1/N x 100 | n2/N x 100|n3/N x 100 |           | 
---------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
             mf      |      n5   |     n6    |     n7    | n5+n6+n7  | 
                     |n5/N x 100 |n6/N x 100 | n7/N x 100|           | 
---------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
               f     |       n8  |      n9   |      n10  |n8+n9+n10  | 
                     |n8/N x 100 |n9/N x 100 |n10/N x 100|           | 
---------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
        Column Total | n1+n5+n8  | n2+n6+n9  |n3+n7+n10  |     N     | 
---------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
```

Is there a way of incorporating weights to the second data. I have looked at 'prop.table(svytable)' but not sure how to proceed, given that I would also like to display the number of observations in each cell and the corresponding percentage.

Thank you in advance

Edit : I have used the svytable and Crosstable functions to achieve my goal.

```
table2 <- svytable(~c_dta$VarA + c_dta$wrd_VarB, design=design)
CrossTable(table2  ,prop.c = FALSE ,prop.r = FALSE , prop.chisq = FALSE , format = "SPSS")
```

Comment: Could you explain briefly what CrossTable does or give a reproducible example ?

Comment: @RémiCoulaud CrossTable gives contingency tables. In this case, I want to know what percentage of respondents are in some category of VarA and at the same time in some category of VarB. I will see if I can put up the crosstable in the main question